# background-image full-path url to my isp ftp?

Tags: html, css, ftp, access-control

I'm hosting my own server for my website, and I would like to store all the resources on my isps ftp instead (like images, scripts and stuff like that) to prevent unnecessary strain on my server, and because my isps network speed ought to be quicker than the service they provide me. Now the fonts and the javascripts work fine, but when I try the following in my css:

```
background-image:url("-url-");
```

It does not want to display on my website, and in chrome I get this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load -url-. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://my-domain-name/' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What does this mean?

-edit-

Actually it does seem to display, but I don't think it is supposed to. But they load up in a weird manner so I think I might just host the files on my own server after all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the format of your URL (I assume you are using http, not ftp to link the image) or the nature of your "IPS's server" but the error suggests it does not allow hotlinking of images (I.e. cross-domain access to the files is not allowed by the server).

What is the service you are using to host the images? If it isn't indended for this purpose and you want to reduce strain on your own server it would make more sense to use a proper CDN service like AWS (they have a free tier I think).